# Zend Framework cannot redeclare class errors using Autoloader

Tags: zend-framework

At seemingly random (I hate to say the word), I am getting the following error with various "Db" classes under the Zend Framework 1.11 when Autoloader tries to load them on demand:

---

**Fatal error**:  Cannot redeclare class Zend_Db_Table_Select in **C:\www\Zend\Db\Table\Select.php** on line **224**

**Fatal error**:  Access to undeclared static property: Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::$_writeClosed in **Unknown** on line **0**

---

The only part of the Zend Framework I explicitly have a "require" line for is the Zend Autoloader, so I don't know why or how these classes are being redeclared:

```
require_once('C:/www/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

What's worse, is as I stated, this seems to happened at random.  Numerous calls to various autoloaded class methods will be made and then out of (seemingly) nowhere this error will happen.  The only way to stop the error from continuing to recur has been to restart the whole web server.  Then its back to a game of Russian roulette with the Zend Autoloader.

I'm really pulling my hair out here and hope someone has an idea what could be going on.  I need to deploy this app across multiple systems soon but can't just tell their admins to restart the whole server whenever this bug occurs. :(

Comment: had exactly the same problem. only solution was to reinstall apache and php on my ubuntu box.

Comment: see [this](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7563?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

Comment: Annoying, but easy enough to do on my development server (overdue for an upgrade anyway), but not so easy on a major ecommerce server.  Is this a bug Zend is working to fix?  I couldn't find anything that suggests it is, though I might have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

Verify that you are not loading your Zend Library twice without wanting to.

i.e. check that the /etc/php.ini or equivalent is not ALSO loading the Zend library somehow, in addition to your own application loader.

The hint here is that the warning indicates you are attempting to redeclare the class.

This points to the class having been preloaded somehow.

Also verify that any includes use absolute, not relative, paths.

Answer (score 0):

remove your path to library in application.ini :)